# shareThis change title when used

Tags: php, javascript, sharethis

I am using ShareThis to integrate social websites with my site. I want to be able to set the title of the share to whatever I like. Right now I am using:

```
<span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js">

                            </script> <script type="text/javascript">           
                                    stLight.options({   
                                        publisher:'12345',        
                                     }); 
                            </script> 


                            <span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
```

I want part of the title to be set dynamically via php variable (name of profile owner).How can this be ddone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information add st_title="Your title" to the span:

```
<span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook' st_title="Your title></span>
```